# How to send PHP email

Tags: php, html

This used to work, but now it won't send the user input, just Message: Email: Name: etc.
   The php should be working, I think it is having trouble retrieving the html maybe?

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$to="fakeemail@sorry.com";
$subject="Tech Muffins Contact";
$message="Name: ".$_REQUEST['name']."\n\nEmail: ".$_REQUEST['email']."\n\nMessage: ".$_REQUEST['message'];
mail($to, $subject, $message, $from );
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tech Muffins</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.ico" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="techmuffins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="virus_min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="hide.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <ul id="menu">
                <a href="">
                    <li id="page">Home</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <li id="contact">Contact
                        <form id="contactform" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" autofocus required>
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
                            <textarea name="message" placeholder="message" required></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </a>
            </ul>
            <div id="currentvid">
                <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NlB4g1IR0nQ?&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0"></iframe>
            </div>
             <h1 id="title">1. Create Billboard</h1> 
            <div id="videos">
                <ul id="videomenu">
                    <a href="NlB4g1IR0nQ" class="youtube">
                        <li id="active">1. Create Billboard</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="DmLffEwMIDA" class="youtube">
                        <li>2. Illustrator Tutorial</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="PhlTstOPF3c" class="youtube">
                        <li>3. Remote Server</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="nmeJrM30pz0" class="youtube">
                        <li>4. Brush Presets</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="N7HldTtKYUg" class="youtube">
                        <li>5. Audio Editing</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="uq3worB22eM" class="youtube">
                        <li>6. Background Editing</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="Px29iXqYQIc" class="youtube">
                        <li>7. PHP Theme Change</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="L6bBsrA4xRo" class="youtube">
                        <li>8. Photoshop Tutorial</li>
                    </a>
                     <a href="2S8kysshs2A" class="youtube">
                        <li>9. Flash Shape Tween</li>
                    </a>


                     <a href="b78XC2LE8bE" class="youtube">
                        <li>10. Shiny Text Tutorial</li>
                    </a>

                        <a href="dZMVmaxPgCM" class="youtube">
                        <li>11. HTML5 Canvas</li>
                    </a>



                    <a href="9vLnfWT9wQ8" class="youtube">
                        <li>adorable.</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="_OBlgSz8sSM" class="youtube">
                        <li>Charlie Bit My Finger</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="9bZkp7q19f0" class="youtube">
                        <li>Gangnam Style</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="1f4AhcX3EyI" class="youtube">
                        <li>MTCHS Harlem Shake</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="AKuBMihmVHQ#t=24s" class="youtube">
                        <li>Mystery</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="DKWdSCt4jGE#t=14s" class="youtube">
                        <li>Stop Motion</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="feCXr86HzMk" class="youtube">
                        <li>DOG</li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="alert">Thank you for visiting my page. It was created with lots of love and frustration. To exit this alert, click on the footer or press escape. Or simply delete system32; that works too.</div>
        <div id="footer">&copy; Josue Espinosa 2013</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

could someone please point me in the right direction on how to email or why it doesnt work?

Comment: By "it doesn't work" what do you mean? How can we help if you don't even tell us your problem?

Comment: Do you get any type of error? Also, I would edit out any identifying information (like your boss' email)

Comment: Is there anything in the mail server logs? Is it trying to send an email, and failing, or is the email being send but ending up in spam? Do you define `$from` anywhere? Does the `$to` address exist? Does it work when you send to a different address?

Comment: the email sends, just the input isnt put into the email just the text i typed.

Comment: The last one in `mail($to, $subject, $message, $from );` should be something along the line of `$headers`, not `$from`. See Lucky Soni's suggestion/answer.

Comment: Try adding the following before the line with $message: `echo "<pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);die();`

Comment: Plus, I don't know if you left out your `form action` on purpose, if not then you should set it to a process or make it as `<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`

Comment: Hey sorry guys. The php was working exactly as is, I think my html is causing errors. I left the action as "" because the same page is the action.

Comment: @jhfgds See my comment above ;-)

Comment: where do I insert that?

Comment: Between your double quotes `""` in `action`. `action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"`

Comment: @jhfgds My above comment will only work if your form is in the same PHP file. Otherwise, you will have to make a process file called `process_message.php` for example and set the action as `action="process_message.php"`.

Comment: where is your trying code?

Comment: @jhfgds You have another error in `<input type="submit" value="submit"></input>` Remove `</input>`, it's not a closeable `tag`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST)){
   $to = "someone@example.com";
   $subject = "Test mail";
   $message = "Name: ".$_POST['name']. "\r\n Email: ".$_POST['email']. "\r\n Message: ".$_POST['message'];
   $from = "someonelse@example.com";
   $headers = "From:" . $from;
   mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   echo "Mail Sent.";
}
```

[See more here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp)